# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'print' referenced before assignment?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a text based rpg styled game. The problem I am having is that it is coming up with:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'print' referenced before assignment

and I don't know why. I have searched online and found that normally it is from global variables being used locally, but I don't understand why this is done with `print`. Also it keeps looping back to the start without reading out the `print` for `def option_statue`. I am using Python 3.7.3:

```
import time
import random

answer_A = ["A", "a"]
answer_B = ["B", "b"]
answer_C = ["C", "c"]
yes = ["Y", "y", "yes"]
no = ["N", "n", "no"]
required = ("\nUse only A, B, or C\n")


hp = 30
sword = 0
flower = 0




goblin_damage = random.randint(1,5)


def intro():
    print("You wake with a start, cold mountain air fills your lungs as a bird cry shatters the serenity of the early morning.")
    print("You rise to your feet and observe your surroundings,it is clear that you are in a forest of some sort, the tall oaken arms of nearby trees strech into the sky")
    print(",they cast a soft shadow on you, and combined with the damp grass beneath your feet, results in a brisk morning awakening")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("How or why you are here remains unknown")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("What will you do now?")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("""A. Look around
B. Sit back down""")


    choice = input (">>> ")
    if choice in answer_A:
        option_lookaround()
    elif choice in answer_B:
        print("\nYou sit back down.\nWell that was fun")
        time.sleep(3)
        print("After lying down for a while, chewing grass and contemplating why you are here, you eventually decide to do something")
        time.sleep(1)
        option_lookaround()
    else:print (required)
    intro()


def option_lookaround():
    print("As you blink the sleep from your eyes, you realize that you are in a grove, in the centre, lies the broken remains of a statue")
    print("to your left you see a small stream and to your right appears to be the glow of a campfire. Will you:")
    print("""A. Explore the statue
B. Walk towards the stream
C. Investigate the campfire""")

    choice = input (">>> ")
    if choice in answer_A:
        option_statue()
    elif choice in answer_B:
        option_stream()
    elif choice in answer_C:
        option_campfire()
    else:
        print (required)
        option_lookaround()

def option_statue():
    global hp
    print:("""The statue appears before you, a grand monument to its era, now faded into obscurity,
it appeared to have been a humanoid of some sort, yet the eons of weather have worn the features to a near unrecognizable state""")
    hp = (hp- goblin_damage)
    print("You now have" ,hp, "health points")


intro()
```

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Python/Text story adventure.py", line 79, in <module>
    intro()
  File "/home/pi/Python/Text story adventure.py", line 39, in intro
    option_lookaround()
  File "/home/pi/Python/Text story adventure.py", line 61, in option_lookaround
    option_statue()
  File "/home/pi/Python/Text story adventure.py", line 76, in option_statue
    print("You now have" ,hp, "health points")
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'print' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: you have a `:` in the statement `print:("""The statue appears...`.

Comment: You also have a space after a print --> ```print (required)```

Comment: The space is optional anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in this line:

```
print:("""The statue appears before you, ...""")
#    ^
#    Specifically here.
```

Have a look at the following transcript, which shows your problem in a smaller code snippet:

```
>>> def fn():
...     print:("Hello there.")
...     print(42)
...
>>> fn()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in fn
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'print' referenced before assignment
```

The `print:("Hello")` is actually a form of the Python type hinting (annotations) and it *looks* like this is simply marking `print` as a local variable (without assigning anything to it), which is why you're seeing the "referenced before assignment" error.

The solution is simply to get rid of the colon:

```
print("""The statue appears before you, ...""")
```

---

As added fun information (well, for *some* weird definition of "fun"), there's nothing really *special* about `print`, you can do all sorts of wonderful things by assigning to it:

```
>>> print(7)
7
>>> print = 42
>>> print(7)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Or coercing it into doing something other than intended, such as outputting `42` despite what you give it (please don't do stuff like this in real code):

```
def newprint(*args):
    global oldprint, print
    try:
        oldprint
    except:
        oldprint = print
        print = newprint
    oldprint(42)

print(7)                         # 7
newprint(7)                      # 42
print(7)                         # 42
print("Hello", "from", "pax")    # 42
```